# How to implement a secondary menu?

Tags: menus

I actually need to implement a secondary vertical menu like in here: http://www.adverum.lt/lt/paslaugos/korporatyvine-komunikacija

It has to be vertical and it looks like it based on frames, but as I know frames are obsolete, so how should I do this? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a sub-menu for the current menu item from another menu - if that makes sense itself ;)

One that I've personally used with great success is [Advanced Menu Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/). Tons of options and does exactly what you want. Thanks!

Features include:

- Custom hierarchy - "Only related sub-items" or "Only strictly related
  sub-items".
- Starting depth and maximum level to display + flat
  display.
- Display all menu items starting with the selected one.
- Display only direct path to current element or only children of
  selected item (option to include the parent item).
- Custom class for a
  widget block.
- And almost all the parameters for the wp_nav_menu
  function.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to guess what exactly you are asking, If I'm not being wrong, that menu is like a list of Wordpress categories. If your theme supports one **[Dynamic Sidebars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)**, then you can simply drag a **[category list widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets)** into it, and a list of all categories will appear in your site's sidebar.

Or

You can **[manually edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar)** your themes sidebar to include wordpress function  - [`wp_list_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), which will list all the categories.